# MvvmCross and AsyncLayoutInflater

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying get binding to work with the AsyncLayoutInflater in Xamarin Android.

Here is my class: The view gets created, but nothing is bound.
Any hints on what I am doing wrong?

```
public static class MvxAsyncBindingExtensions
{
    private static readonly AsyncLayoutInflater _inflater = new AsyncLayoutInflater(AndroidContext.CurrentTopActivity);

    public static Task<View> BindingInflateAsync(this IMvxBindingContextOwner owner, int resourceId, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        var context = (IMvxAndroidBindingContext)owner.BindingContext;
        return context.BindingInflateAsync(resourceId, viewGroup);
    }

    public static Task<View> BindingInflateAsync(this IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext, int resourceId, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<View>();
        var registration = new MvxBindingContextStackRegistration<IMvxAndroidBindingContext>(bindingContext);
        var listener = new AsyncInflateFinishedListener(tcs, view => registration.Dispose());
        _inflater.Inflate(resourceId, viewGroup, listener);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    private class AsyncInflateFinishedListener : Java.Lang.Object, AsyncLayoutInflater.IOnInflateFinishedListener
    {
        private readonly TaskCompletionSource<View> _tcs;
        private readonly Action<View> _onCreated;

        public AsyncInflateFinishedListener(TaskCompletionSource<View> tcs, Action<View> onCreated)
        {
            _tcs = tcs;
            _onCreated = onCreated;
        }

        public void OnInflateFinished(View p0, int p1, ViewGroup p2)
        {
            _tcs.TrySetResult(p0);
            _onCreated(p0);
        }
    }
}
```

then I use it as followed:

```
private async Task<View> CreateAndBindViewAsync(FilterItemEntity item)
{
    var sourceBindingContext = this.BindingContext as MvxAndroidBindingContext;
    var bindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(this.Context, sourceBindingContext.LayoutInflaterHolder);
    var view = await bindingContext.BindingInflateAsync(_itemTemplateId, _flowLayout);
    bindingContext.DataContext = item;
    return view;
}
```

I have similar code that works with the normal `BindingInflate` extension just fine.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36156773), I think AsyncLayoutInflater.LayoutInflater should be set with context.LayoutInflater but LayoutInflater is private in [AsyncLayoutInflater](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/89f7eba/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/AsyncLayoutInflater.java), so there's no way to do that.

But you have another option. After inflate finished, you can make a programatically bind:

```
        using (var bindingSet = this.CreateBindingSet<your_activity, your_view_model>())
        {
            bindingSet.Bind(view.TextView).To(vm => vm.Text);
            bindingSet.Apply();
        }
```